# How i can save an javafx.image.Image to a jpg file in a javafxports android app?

Tags: javafxports, gluon-mobile

How i can save an javafx.image.Image to a jpg file in a javafxports android app?
I can't find an api the only i have founded is ImageIO that is not supported on android.
i need some help 
Example code:

@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

```
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 450);
    WritableImage wim = new WritableImage(300, 250);



    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 250);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    drawShapes(gc);
    canvas.snapshot(null, wim);
    root.getChildren().add(canvas);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    File file = new File("CanvasImage.png");


    try {

       //on desktop ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(wim, null), "png", file);
//   on android ??????????

    } catch (Exception s) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify: Where do you get the image from? Where would you save the image? 
Have you seen the GoNative [sample](http://gluonhq.com/support/samples/)? It deals with images on the Android package, saving them to external storage public directory.

Comment: I changed the questions with some code to explain better the request

Comment: So you want to be able to snapshot a canvas and store the result in a png file. Where this image has to be stored? private storage (in case you want to retrieve it later), or public storage (to be able to download it)?

Answer (score 1):

On Android you can use android.graphics.Bitmap to save to file:

```
  public void saveImageToPngFile(File file, WritableImage image) {
    int width = (int) image.getWidth();
    int height = (int) image.getHeight();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    try {

        PixelReader pr = image.getPixelReader();
        IntBuffer buffer = IntBuffer.allocate(width * height);
        pr.getPixels(0, 0, width, height, PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(), buffer, width);
        bitmap.setPixels(buffer.array(), 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```